# XConnect Indexworker Solr error: parentFilter=filterCondition

Tags: solr, xconnect, docker

I am running an out-of-the-box XP 9.3 installation (using the Sitecore Community Docker images) and get the following Solr related error in the XConnect Indexworker:

```
2020-01-27 15:27:38.096 +01:00 [Error] An error occured during resuming a previous index rebuild process. There will be another attempt to check. The check interval after an error is 00:00:20.
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrResponseException: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:xdb-rebuild-status",
      "fl":"*,[child limit=1024]",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Parent filter should be sent as parentFilter=filterCondition",
    "code":400}}

   at    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.EnsureSolrSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.<SendGetRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.<ExecuteTaskWithRetryAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.TaskRetryHelper.<ExecuteTaskWithRetryAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.<SendGetRequestAsyncWithRetries>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.<ReadStatus>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<TryToResumeRebuild>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.RebuildStatusWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Start>g__RunRebuildFlowCycle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.TaskExtension.<ExecuteWithInterval>d__0.MoveNext()
...
```

Any clues?

Comment: The `fl` parameter in the query to search the nested child documents is missing the mandatory parentFilter parameter, and so Solr is returning a Bad Request response (https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/transform/ChildDocTransformerFactory.java#L100). Can you share the full detailed error exception to see where this request originates in the XConnect indexworker code?

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo added the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this issue if I delete the `<field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" />` field definition in the `managed-schema.xml` file for the `xdb` and the `xdb_rebuild` indexes.

The schema for these two indexes is supposed to be nested. According to [Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/transforming-result-documents.html#child-childdoctransformerfactory) for the `[child]` transformer, when using this transformer, the `parentFilter` parameter must be specified unless the schema declares _nest_path_. In this case, since the `xdb` and the `xdb_rebuild` indexes are supposed to be nested, the `parentFilter` parameter can be omitted in the queries.

The XConnect indexworker queries the status of the rebuild task invoking the `Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.ReadStatus()` task. In this task, the internal GetJsonSearchByIdUri method is invoked to build the Solr search request uri. This code assumes that the Solr index is nested and indeed the `parentFilter` parameter is not used:

```
internal static Uri GetJsonSearchByIdUri(Uri uri, string id, bool includeChildren)
{
    string str1 = "id:" + Uri.EscapeDataString(id);
    string str2 = includeChildren ? "&fl=*,[child%20limit=1024]" : string.Empty;
    return new Uri(uri, "select?wt=json&q=" + str1 + str2);
}
```

It seems that the `managed-schema.xml` for the `xdb` and the `xdb_rebuild` indexes in your Solr docker container might be corrupted.

Comment: A manual rebuild does not solve it. The xdb Solr cores are both empty, except for one document in xdb: {"id":"xdb-rebuild-status","progresscurrent_d":0.0, "rebuildstate_l":1, ...}. Starting with fresh Solr cores results in the same problem.

Comment: How did you trigger the rebuild process? Invoking the rebuild request command ("XConnectSearchIndexer -r” command) or manually posting a rebuild document?

Comment: I used "XConnectSearchIndexer -rr"

Comment: @Joost I rewrote my answer since I stated something incorrect before.

Comment: That solves it; I got the wrong the xdb Solr schema (v9.2) without the "_nest_path". NB. Not a Sitecore Docker XP related issue, my fault of re-using Solr cores from disk.